# Create a new filter in Gmail using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I want to create a new label and a new filter in Gmail using Google Apps Script which will push all new emails in a particular label. I have already created a label which is working fine but I am unable to create a filter.

I know it's easy to create a new filter in the search criteria of GMail. But I want to automate exactly the same feature and then publish it to my team of 100 people so they don't have to do it manually.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Prachi

Comment: There are official samples you can start. See the official docs amd post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Zig Mandel - Thanks for reply. I wrote the following code which creates a new label Public if it's not already there. Now I want to create a filter which would move all emails to this label if they have come from abc@xyz.com and would do the same when a new e-mail comes.  function doGet(e) {

    var label_text = "Public";
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_text);
    if (label == null) {
    var label = GmailApp.createLabel(label_text);
    }
    }

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I couldn't get it right.

Comment: That code only creates a label

Comment: @Zig Mandel After this I wrote following code. This code puts label in front of the mail but do not move mail to label folder. And I couldn't find how to create a filter such that when a new mail comes it goes to the label folder if condition is met. It may seem I didn't go through documentation but I did a lot of research before posting the question here.  My apologies if this question is answered somewhere - I just couldn't find.

Comment: var label_text = "Public";
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_text);
if (label == null) {
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel(label_text);
}

   var threads = GmailApp.search('to:birudvora@gmail.com');
     for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
       label.addToThread(threads[i]);
     }
}

Comment: Look at all the methods available. I dont know them by heart but either there is a moveXX/removefrominbox/archive so it moves out of inbox

Comment: @Zig Mandel Thanks very much for your response. I went through the methods here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#moveThreadToInbox%28GmailThread%29 . There are options like movetoinbox;movetotrash;movetoarchive and movetospam but there is no method to move to a label/folder. Also there is no method to create a filter as well. Hence I am asking here if someone can guide me how this should be done?

Comment: no need to create a gmail filter. add a label, then archive. that is a "move".

Comment: @ZigMandel That's working great. I just didn't realize movetoArchive actually moves to a particular folder. I still have a question though. When a new mail comes I want it to move to label if the condition is met same as filter. Currently I have set a trigger which runs the above code every minute. But this is inefficient. Is there a way we can set a trigger when a new mail comes or create a filter? Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: curently there is no way to run is "when mail arrives" so the trigger is your only option. however, you could speed it up by creating a gmail filter that does some of the job (like applying the labels) so when you trigger runs, some stuff is already done.

Comment: @ZigMandel Thanks Zig. It's working now thanks to your help. One question can you create a filter through script? Because I want to create a filter and then publish it to my team of 100 so they do not have to create it manually themselves. I just couldn't find an option to do it through Apps-Script. Once again I really appreciate your help. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update 2016: the new gmail api can create filters.
Currently you cannot create gmail filters using apps script but it can be done without filters.
Using apps script, add a label then archive (moveToArchive). that is a "move" out of the inbox and into the label.

A gmail filter is better because it does the "apply label and archive" real-time while the apps script can run at most once per minute using a time trigger.

Comment: Thanks Zig. A small follow up on this - When I trigger the script every minute I got the failure message that service invoked too many times in a day. Can you tell how to avoid this as I need to run this script every minute and script checks for mails for the condition and if the condition is met it moves it to label folder using moveToArchive. Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to optimize the script but thats beyond this question scope.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will look into optimization of the script. Can you please send me a good link from where I can start reading? Once again Thanks Very much for your help.

Comment: The apps script docs have a section on good practices. See there. Not everything is possible to optimize.

Comment: If you get stuck post a new question with code and what you tried