# Is there a way to make emails skip the inbox without a filter in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to create a filter in Apps script only, but in order for my filter to work I need a function the can make an email skip the inbox. Something like this,

```
threads[i].markRead();
threads[i].addLabel(important);
threads[i].skipInbox()
```

There is a function

```
.moveToInbox()
```

But I cant find one that does the opposite.
Could someone suggest how to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appositive to `moveToInbox()` is `moveToarchive()`;

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#movetoarchive

Related

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008046/1595451